# Change color on object after 3d extrude and bevel and transform

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, transform

I have google this but can not find an answer to my specific problem.

I am using Illustrator CC (2015)

I am new to illustrator, but know the basics and am learning as I go along using different tools.

I have created a simple shape:

[image]

and used 3d extrude and bevel  and transform. Up to this point I can still change the colour.

I then use the transform effect and expand appearance

[image]

[image]

When I re color like in the last image it doesn't change the face. I have tried changing colour of the stroke and fill I just can't figure it out.

What I am trying to do is to have each with a different color.

Comment: Couldn't post these due to points
 [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4mJux.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/V4ZOL.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realize that gradients get rasterized when using the 3D effects.

There's a warning in the 3D dialog window if the art contains a gradient:

[image]

**That** may be why colors aren't changing -- they are embedded raster images after the 3D effect is applied and expanded.

Don't use gradients in the *base* object, use flat colors, then apply the 3D, expand, and then change colors.

Answer (score 0):

Not using a gradient as Scott said helped, however when changing color it changed all including the shadow. To just change the face color I used the direct selection tool.

It also worked on the image I had already created by selecting the face (using direct selection tool), dragging it off, selecting where the face was and then selecting a new colour.

I did that because for some reason I could not recreate the same image.

I hope that explained what I did, it was simpler doing it than trying to explain what I did

Comment: It sounds like you essentially deleted the embedded raster image then added a fill color to its clipping mask. That works, but having filled clipping masks *may* cause issues later. You may want to reselect those fills and choose `Object > Clipping Mask > Release` to remove the clipping aspect of those shapes.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can just expand the appearance after you're done with the shapes and then manipulate the colours once expanded